# Cannot create scroll effect on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a look that allows when a user press the "Scroll" button, the page will scroll with sliding effect. But it does not work on my page. I tried add with  tag to my html file but it does not work too.

I found a script for that but it did not work.

Where is my mistake?

**home.html**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="{% static 'js/home.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/home.css' %}">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
.
.
.
    <section id="section01" class="demo">

      <h1> Welcome to PHARSYS  </h1>
      <h2>Scroll for Login or Signup</h2>

      <a href="#section02"><span></span></a>
    </section>
    <section id="section02" class="demo">
      <h1>Login</h1><br>
        <h2>Press the button to log in to the system.
      <br><br>

      </h2>
      <a href="#section03"><span></span>Scroll</a>
    </section>
    <section id="section03" class="demo">
      <h1>Signup</h1>
        <h2>Press the button to register to the system</h2>
    </section>
```

**home.js**

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 500, 'linear');
  });
});
```

**home.css**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,400);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
section::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.8) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,.8) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(0,0,0,0) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.8) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,.8) 100%);
}
section h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font : normal 300 64px/1 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

section h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font : normal 200 24px/1 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#section01 { background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=575) center center / cover no-repeat;}
#section02 { background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=1016) center center / cover no-repeat;}
#section03 { background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=869) center center / cover no-repeat;}


.demo a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font : normal 400 20px/1 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}
.demo a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

#section01 a {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
#section01 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  margin-left: -23px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#section01 a span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  content: '';
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -8px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#section01 a span::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: sdb03 3s infinite;
  animation: sdb03 3s infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sdb03 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 60px rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes sdb03 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 60px rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}



#section02 a {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
#section02 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  margin-left: -23px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#section02 a span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  content: '';
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -8px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



#section03 a {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
#section03 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  margin-left: -23px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#section03 a span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  content: '';
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -8px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#section03 a span::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: sdb03 3s infinite;
  animation: sdb03 3s infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sdb03 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 60px rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes sdb03 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 60px rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was here

```
$('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(e) { ...
```

To target the anchor elements that have a `href` attribute which begin with the `#` character you would use `^` (instead of `*`), which means *starts with*, and you would also add some parentheses around the search character like this

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) { ...
```

Check below:

**Note:** I purposefully gave the body a height of 1000px so we can test and run here.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 500, 'linear');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  src="{% static 'js/home.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/home.css' %}">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section id="section01" class="demo">

  <h1> Welcome to PHARSYS  </h1>
  <h2>Scroll for Login or Signup</h2>

  <a href="#section02"><span></span></a>
</section>
<section id="section02" class="demo">
  <h1>Login</h1><br>
    <h2>Press the button to log in to the system.
  <br><br>

  </h2>
  <a href="#section03"><span></span>Scroll</a>
</section>
<section id="section03" class="demo">
  <h1>Signup</h1>
    <h2>Press the button to register to the system</h2>
</section>
```

You can also use the `*` as a wild card instead of `^`, which will then match anchor elements that have a `#` character anywhere in their `href` attribute, and not just begin with `#`.